# Prove that the phase of the mean of a set of complex numbers is weighted average of phases

Tags: complex-numbers, random-variables, means

I'm wondering if its correct (and possible to prove) that the phase of the mean of a set of complex numbers is equivalent to the weighted average of the phases of the set where the weights are the magnitudes.

Given a set of complex numbers $z_j$ we have
\begin{align}
    z_j &= x_j + iy_j = r_j e^{i\theta_j}\\
    \langle z \rangle &= \langle x \rangle + i \langle y \rangle = \bar{r} e^{i\bar{\theta}}
\end{align}

Where the expected value of a variable ($\langle x \rangle$) has its usual meaning and $\bar{r}$ and $\bar{\theta}$ have the following definitions:

\begin{align}
    \bar{r} &= \sqrt{\langle x \rangle^2 + \langle y \rangle^2}\\
    \bar{\theta} &= \arctan\frac{\langle y \rangle}{\langle x \rangle}
\end{align}

My question at the beginning then becomes:

\begin{equation}
    \bar{\theta} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\langle r\theta \rangle}{\langle r\rangle}
\end{equation}

I've tried expanding either side of the equation but an arctan always shows up that I can't get rid of, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the noise.

Comment: But wait, you have $\langle y\rangle = 1/2$ and $\langle x \rangle = 1$. Hence, $\arctan(\langle y\rangle /\langle x \rangle) = \arctan(1/2) = 0.46364760 \ne \pi/6$. (it should be $\pi/6$, shouldn't it?)

Comment: You'll have to stop deleting your comments, I lost track already.

Comment: Take $z_1 = 2$ and $z_2 = i$. Then, $\langle z \rangle = 1 + i/2$ with phase $\arctan(1/2) = 0.4636476$. But $\langle r \theta \rangle = \pi/4$, $\langle r\rangle = 3/2$, thus $\langle r \theta \rangle /\langle r\rangle = \pi/3 = \pi/6 = 0.523599$.